# Model MVC Express API - Error "connection.query is not a function"

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to build an mvc model API. I'm having troubles making queries. It seems like I don't export my connection variable correctly, cause I've got a "connection.query is not a function" error.

I've tried to export it using exports.module but as I already have router to export, I had this error : TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

I also tried this syntax to export : exports.connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... }) But the problem is connection.connect()
 which is following, is not recognized anymore, so I don't know if I'm well connected

Here is index.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var indexController =  require('../controllers/IndexController');
var booksController = require('../controllers/BooksController');


connection = mysql.createConnection({  
    debug:true, 
    host:'localhost',
    user:'user',
    password:'password',
    database:'database'
});


  connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error){
      console.log(error);
    }else{
      console.log('Connected!:)');
    }
 });


router.get('/', indexController.index);
router.get('/books', booksController.books);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is booksController.js  :

```
var BooksModel = require('../models/BooksModel');

exports.books = async function(req, res, next){
    res.send(await BooksModel.getAllBooks(req, res))
}
```

Here is booksModel.js :

```
var connection = require('../routes/index');

async function getAllBooks(req, res){
    return await 
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM books", function (error,results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.json(results);
        });
    });
}

module.exports={
    getAllBooks
}
```

I expect to get data coming from my database, according to the query request. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It's because your connection query is out of the scope. You're returning the router in the index.js file.*

*Try to set it in another class : (imagine a database folder with connection.js file)*

```
// database/connection.js
module.exports = () => {
connection = mysql.createConnection({  
    debug:true, 
    host:'localhost',
    user:'user',
    password:'password',
    database:'database'
});


  connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error){
      console.log(error);
    }else{
      console.log('Connected!:)');
    }
 });

  return connection;
}
```

*Then in your model*

```
var getConnection = require('../database/connection');

async function getAllBooks(req, res){
    return await 
    getConnection().query("SELECT * FROM books", function (error,results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.json(results);
        });
    });
}

module.exports={
    getAllBooks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of export default router from index.js file export module
Here is index.js

replace your code last line

```
module.exports = {
    router,
    connection 
};
```

Now in booksModel.js, you can use them

```
var { connection } = require('../routes/index');
```

in app.js/server.js/start.js if needed

```
var { router } = require('../routes/index');
```

Comment: Thanks, but having 2 modules to export doesn't work for me. I had this error : "TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn)) TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object ."

Comment: Then seprate connection and router code in separate files and export them default.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did !